# Is there a way to catch an onchange trigger with a focusout by a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, odoo

The scenario is this modal window:

[image]

The inputs 2, 3 and 4 with an `.on('change', function () {});` makes an AJAX call to a specified controller, that update the recod values and reload the value 1.
So the right, but not functional way is to:

1. click the input 1 and set the value
2. focusout it by clicking outside the input
3. AJAX reload value 1 updated
4. click input 2 and set the value
5. focus out it by clicking outside the input
6. AJAX reload value 1 updated
7. The user click confirm that call another controller that make some checks and change the status of an object (from Draft to Confirmed)

**The problem**

If I try this way:

8. click the input 1 and set the value
9. focusout it by clicking outside the input
10. AJAX reload value 1 updated
11. click input 2 and set the value
12. Click confirm button that call another controller and trigger the input change

Now, with this way the problem occurs because the confirm method doesn't receive yet the update from last onchange trigger and the check is not correct.

Is there a way to manage multiple AJAX from different triggers like `onchange` and `onclick`?

Something like if the below onclick is triggered:

```
// Trigger for button confirm inside timesheet sheet modal
$(document).on('click', 'button.js_confirm_timesheet_sheet', function (ev) {
    var $button = $(this);
    var wizard_id = $button.data()['wizardId'];
    var sheet_id = $button.data()['sheetId'];
    var values = {
        'wizard_id': wizard_id,
        'sheet_id': sheet_id,
    };
    confirm_sheet_distribution_hours(values);
});
```

Check if the click come from an input focus out, if yes trigger the `onchange` first and after the `onclick`

Maybe this solution can be a bad way to do this.

**Little, triggers recap:**

- The inputs have an onchange trigger that writes data to backend object with an AJAX call that recompute values and return the new one
- The confirm button check if everything is ok with an AJAX call and change the backend object status

The other workaround maybe can be to declare an object that keeps track of each changed input boxes and clear it on each AJAX success return.

Something like:

```
var changedData = {};

function update_wizard_data_and_modal(values, $input_elem, event) {
    changedData[key] = $input_elem;
    ajax.jsonRpc("/my/controller/path", "call", values)
        .then(function (new_modal_values) {
            $input_elem.removeClass('input-value-error');
            if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(new_modal_values)) {
                if (new_modal_values.error_msg) {
                    var $content = $(new_modal_values.error_msg);
                    $content.modal({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        keyboard: false
                    });
                    $content.appendTo('body').modal();
                    // Show error class
                    $input_elem.val('00:00');
                    $input_elem.addClass('input-value-error');
                }
                // Update the header values with hours to be distribuited
                $('#header-wizard-values').html(new_modal_values.header_values);
                // Update the hours to get payed available
                $('.js_hours_to_get_payed').html(new_modal_values.hours_get_payed_values);
                // Clear the changedData object
                for (var member in changedData) delete changedData[member];
            }
        });
}

function confirm_sheet_distribution_hours(values) {
    if jQuery.isEmptyObject(changedData){
        ajax.jsonRpc("/confirm/controller/path", "call", values)
            .then(function (response) {
                if ('error' in response) {
                    //response in this case is the modal error template
                    $(response.error).appendTo('body').modal();
                } else {
                    // Close modal and refresh the grid for current period
                    $('#modal_timesheet_sheet_confirm').modal('hide');
                    var sheet_item_data = {
                        'year': response.year,
                        'month': response.month,
                    };
                    update_grid_and_bars_values(sheet_item_data);
                }

            });
    } else {
       // TODO: trigger the change for element inside object and confirm
    }
}


$(document).on("change", "input.distribution-input", function (ev) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var sheet_id = $('input[name="sheet_id"]').val();
    var wiz_line_id = Number($input.attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0]);
    var row_wizard_data = $input.closest('div.row').data();
    var leave_type_id = row_wizard_data['leaveTypeId'];
    var wizard_id = row_wizard_data['wizardId'];
    var values = {
        'sheet_id': Number(sheet_id),
        'wizard_id': wizard_id,
        'wiz_line_id': wiz_line_id,
        'leave_type_id': leave_type_id,
        'input_value': $input.val(),
    };
    var is_good_formatted = check_string_time_format($input, {});
    if (is_good_formatted) {
        update_wizard_data_and_modal(values, $input, ev);
    }
});

// Trigger for button confirm inside timesheet sheet modal
$(document).on('click', 'button.js_confirm_timesheet_sheet', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    var $button = $(this);
    var wizard_id = $button.data()['wizardId'];
    var sheet_id = $button.data()['sheetId'];
    var values = {
        'wizard_id': wizard_id,
        'sheet_id': sheet_id,
    };
    confirm_sheet_distribution_hours(values);
});
```

Comment: How about disabling the submit button so long as there is an outstanding change call?

Comment: @Taplar the problem is that when user click the confirm button from an input changed the first call is the on('click') and the last the on('change').
Is there a way to check if before the click, there is an onchange?

Comment: `input` would happen immediately when the field value changes.  So you could on `input` disable the submit, and then re-enable it after the change ajax finishes.

Comment: Is this a change/extension to Odoo itself or something that is just communicating with Odoo? Because Odoo already has computed fields functionality you could use here, instead of writing a whole JS tool.

Comment: @CZoellner it's a portal functionality so the backend api.onchange() and api.depends can't be used.
It's Odoo, but website side :)

Comment: Ah okay, that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Taplar I used a similar approach.

Here the javascript that manages the "onchange" of a wizard in the Odoo Frontend.

```
// Variable used for the last input changed when user click the Confirm button
var canConfirm = true;
/* Variable used for keep trace of the number of retry inside method
 * confirm_sheet_distribution_hours
 * */
var nr_of_try = 0;

function update_wizard_data_and_modal(values, $input_elem, event) {
    if (event.type !== 'input') {
        ajax.jsonRpc("/controller/path/...", "call", values)
            .then(function (new_modal_values) {
                canConfirm = true;
                $input_elem.removeClass('input-value-error');
                if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(new_modal_values)) {
                    if (new_modal_values.error_msg) {
                        var $content = $(new_modal_values.error_msg);
                        $content.modal({
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: false
                        });
                        $content.appendTo('body').modal();
                        // Show error class
                        $input_elem.val('00:00');
                        $input_elem.addClass('input-value-error');
                    }
                    // Update the header values with hours to be distribuited
                    $('#header-wizard-values').html(new_modal_values.header_values);
                    // Update the hours to get payed available
                    $('.js_hours_to_get_payed').html(new_modal_values.hours_get_payed_values);
                }
            });
    } else {
        canConfirm = false;
    }
}

function set_the_amount_on_wizard($input, values, event) {
    if (event.type !== 'input') {
        ajax.jsonRpc("/controller/path/...", "call", values)
            .then(function (response) {
                canConfirm = true;
                if ('error' in response) {
                    //response in this case is the modal error template
                    $(response.error).appendTo('body').modal();
                    // Reset input value (backend reset the TransientModel value)
                    $input.val('00:00')
                }
            });
    } else {
        canConfirm = false;
    }
}

function confirm_sheet_distribution_hours(values) {
    if (canConfirm) {
        ajax.jsonRpc("/controller/patH/...", "call", values)
            .then(function (response) {
                if ('error' in response) {
                    //response in this case is the modal error template
                    $(response.error).appendTo('body').modal();
                } else {
                    // Close modal and refresh the grid for current period
                    $('#modal_timesheet_sheet_confirm').modal('hide');
                    var sheet_item_data = {
                        'year': response.year,
                        'month': response.month,
                    };
                    update_grid_and_bars_values(sheet_item_data);
                }

            });
    } else {
        /*Try six times to confirm the sheet (Until the onchange doesn't write 
         * new values the AJAX call doesn't set canConfirm as True
         * */
        if (nr_of_try <= 5) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nr_of_try++;
                confirm_sheet_distribution_hours(values);
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}

//Trigger that monitorate hours distribution change
$(document).on("input change", "input.distribution-input", function (ev) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var sheet_id = $('input[name="sheet_id"]').val();
    var wiz_line_id = Number($input.attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0]);
    var row_wizard_data = $input.closest('div.row').data();
    var leave_type_id = row_wizard_data['leaveTypeId'];
    var wizard_id = row_wizard_data['wizardId'];
    var values = {
        'sheet_id': Number(sheet_id),
        'wizard_id': wizard_id,
        'wiz_line_id': wiz_line_id,
        'leave_type_id': leave_type_id,
        'input_value': $input.val(),
    };
    var is_good_formatted = check_string_time_format($input);
    if (is_good_formatted) {
        update_wizard_data_and_modal(values, $input, ev);
    }
});

//Trigger that monitorate hours distribution change
$(document).on("input change", "input.payment-hour-input", function (ev) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var row_wizard_data = $input.closest('div.row').data();
    var wizard_id = row_wizard_data['wizardId'];
    var values = {
        'wizard_id': wizard_id,
        'input_value': $input.val(),
    };
    var is_good_formatted = check_string_time_format($input);
    if (is_good_formatted) {
        set_the_amount_on_wizard($input, values, ev);
    }
});

// Trigger for button confirm inside timesheet sheet modal
$(document).on('click', 'button.js_confirm_timesheet_sheet', function (ev) {
    var $button = $(this);
    var wizard_id = $button.data()['wizardId'];
    var sheet_id = $button.data()['sheetId'];
    var values = {
        'wizard_id': wizard_id,
        'sheet_id': sheet_id,
    };
    // Variable used for retry sheet confirmation until canConfirm is not True
    // Max repeat call is 6 times
    nr_of_try = 0;
    confirm_sheet_distribution_hours(values);
});
```

In simple words.
When the user is typing on inputs boxes the type `input` inside `on.()` set the variable `canConfirm` to `false`.
This prevents case when user changes values and click to the Confirm buttons immediately after.

In fact if the user changes some input box and immediately click "Confirm" the AJAX call starts only if the flag is `true`, if not the method calls it's self six times every 500 ms.

Let me know if there is some better way to doing that.
Thanks

PS: I will try a better approach with a DTO backend that clone data from model and manage updates like onchange cache.

Inspired by: https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Messenger.html